# gcloud distribution was not found and is required by the application - python pyinstaller

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase and the data is stored in there. I am accesing it using the firebase module in python

Here's the code:

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication(
    'link to my project in firebase', None)

result = firebase.get('/', None)
print(result)
```

my o/p:

```
{'name':'steven}
```

It works great and its so easy to use.  But when i converted it to application using pyinstaller, it shows the following below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firebase_connect.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "firebase/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "gcloud/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
  File "pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
  File "pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
  File "pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'gcloud' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[14554] Failed to execute script firebase_connect
```

I tried searching stack overflow but they states that `google cloud` has changed to `gcloud`, so change it in PyInstaller hooks in spec file. But in my error, my pyinstaller file is already checking for `gcloud` and shows that gcloud not found. How to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer.. It's a naming issue

In Ubuntu:

```
cd /home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/
vim hook-gcloud.py
```

Change the content to the following:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = copy_metadata('gcloud')
```

Now create an executable file - it will work great..

Answer (score 2):

You need additional hooks to use `firebase` and `gcloud` while converting to `.exe` using **PyInstaller**

Create a python file (*.py) at some directory and name it - `hook-gcloud.py` and write the following code in it -

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata
datas = copy_metadata('gcloud')
```

Now while giving command for pyinstaller use the option `--additional-hooks-dir`.

Example -
If your newly created `hook-gcloud.py` is located at `C:\Users\xyz\Hooks` and say you need to convert `example.py` to `example.exe` then your command in command prompt will be -

```
pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir C:\Users\xyz\Hooks example.py
```

And you can always use other options like `--onefile` along with this.

Answer (score 0):

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'gcloud' distribution was not found and is required by the application [21369] Failed to execute script

I solved this problem by copy pasting the missing resource gcloud from Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages to dist folder where my .exe file is saved :)

Hope this solves your problem too.